# ¿Cómo hacer compatible FloatingActionsMenu con kitkat 4.4?

Tags: android, material-design, kitkat

tengo un FloatingActionsMenu de esta forma:

```
 <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="#ede686"
    app:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#f7f7f5"
    app:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/digits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="irDigits"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="@string/digits" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="irFactoring"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="@string/factors"

        />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="irEquality"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        app:fab_size="mini"
        app:fab_title="@string/equality" />


</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

cuando pruebo el app en un dispositivo con kitkat 4.4 esta se trunca, ¿Cómo puedo lograr la compatibildad con kitkat?, ya que hasta donde se material design fue introducido en api 21 lollipop, de antemano gracias por su valioso tiempo.

mi archivo build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "matgic.com.matgic"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    aaptOptions
            {
                additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
            }
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando la clase:

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
```

Pero esto no es recomendable, para tener soporte en versiones anteriores usa la clase:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

para esto debes agregar la dependencia en tu archivo `build.gradle`, que sería:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Gracias por tu invaluable ayuda hemano, aún persiste el problema, seguiré intentando, saludos!

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Si deseas utilizar el botón flotante debes usar la clase de soporte (support) android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton , tengo aplicaciones que incluso funcionan desde API 15 , cual es el minSdkVersion defnido en tu build.gradle?

Comment: 14 es el minsdkversion definido

Comment: @Sergio que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: por favor tiempo, compila gradle y mi maquina no ayuda mucho

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76182/discussion-between-elenasys-and-sergio).